# jQuery calendar conflict with mootool images slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins

```
<script src='<?php echo $fullpath; ?>lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo $fullpath; ?>lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo $fullpath; ?>fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $fullpath; ?>js/invite_mail_ajax_full.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $fullpath; ?>js/ajax_BannerAd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $fullpath; ?>script/mootools-core-1.3.1-full-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $fullpath; ?>script/slideitmoo-1.2-mootools-1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $fullpath; ?>auto/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();          
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#tag").autocomplete(fullpath+"autocomplete.php", {

        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();          
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#tag2").autocomplete(fullpath+"autocomplete2.php", {

        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
 <style type="text/css">
 img, div, ul, li, a { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc) }
 </style>
<![endif]-->  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: [
<?php echo $rdiv;?>
            ]
        });

    });

</script> 
<style>
    #calendar {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
.event_cal_title{font-size: 16px;color: teal;}
</style>
</head>
```

The above code accepts only jQuery calender mootools slider not works..

Please help me...

I get an error:

> TypeError:$(---)not a function in **slideitmoo-1.2-mootools-1.3.js**

How to solve this problem?

I have read in many forums and implemented it in the above mentioned manner. and still the code is not working... Any help will be highly apprecited

Thank you

Comment: you are using `noConflict()` so `$` is no longer alias for jQuery. Use word `jQuery` just like your other code does.  [noConflict() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: yes.but i also use alias for calendar.if i use noconflict()  and jQuery instead of $ the calendar doen't work...

Answer (score 0):

Please check by adding jquery conflict code just below the include file. as follow.

```
<script src='<?php echo $fullpath; ?>lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery.noConflict() then the dollar sign "$" is no longer connected to jQuery.

Use the word jQuery instead of the dollar in your code.

Like you have on the first script do same in the second:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: [
           <?php echo $rdiv;?>
        ]
    });

});
```

This happens because both Mootools and jQuery want to use the dollar. In Mootools the dollar is for geting elements thru ID, wich can also be replaced by `document.id('elementId');` (instead of `$('elementId');`)

More about [**jQuery.noConflict();**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: @MohamedaliJinna, Happy I could help! Did you get it working? if this solved your problem you are welcome to click to accept the answer